# VS is telling me that "the name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context" regardless of container datatype even though I just had initialized it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm doing a homework assignment in my ASP.net (core) class to make a simple MVC app that displays a list (or array or whatever) of students and will only display their names if the user is not of a high enough level (but this will come later). I've got the model named StudentModel finished and am trying to creating a global array of StudentModels inside of the controller so that I can use them to display the info inside it in the cshtml file where they are to be displayed.

Here is my StudentModel code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CIS174_TestCoreApp.Models
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public double Grade { get; set; }

        public void SetInfo(string firstName, string lastName, double grade)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Grade = grade;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CIS174_TestCoreApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CIS174_TestCoreApp.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {

        //List<StudentModel> students = new List<StudentModel>();

        public StudentModel[] S = new StudentModel[5];
        S[0] = new StudentModel;
        S[0].SetInfo("Harry", "Potter", 3.0);

        //students.Add(new StudentModel {FirstName = "Harry", LastName = "Potter", Grade = 3.0});

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            StudentModel model = new StudentModel();
            return View(model);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(StudentModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I putting this array in the wrong place or something? I just wanna be able to use the array in my razor tags on the cshtml output page. You can see in the code where I tried to do the same thing with a list but it causes this exact same error regardless of what datatype I use to contain the objects. Even a single object does not work. Also, after this main question is figured out, if you could also point me in the right direction of using this array in the display page, that would be very nice too.

Comment: Should `S[0] = new StudentModel;` not be `S[0] = new StudentModel();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I putting this array in the wrong place or something?

Yes. You are writing statements inside your class definition.
They need to be inside a method. You can put them in your constructor.

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public StudentController()
    {
        StudentModel[] S = new StudentModel[5];
        S[0] = new StudentModel;
        S[0].SetInfo("Harry", "Potter", 3.0);
    }

    ... your actions
}
```

If you want this to be a member, you can define the member in your class definition, but the initialization happens in a method.

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public StudentModel[] S;

    public StudentController()
    {
        S = new StudentModel[5];
        S[0] = new StudentModel;
        S[0].SetInfo("Harry", "Potter", 3.0);
    }

    ... your actions
}
```

If you want to initialize it in the definition, you need slightly different syntax.

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public StudentModel[] S = new StudentModel[]
    {
         new StudentModel { FirstName = "Harry", LastName = "Potter", Grade = 3.0 }
    };

    ... your actions
}
```

...but doing it this way means you cannot call your SetInfo method, because everything needs to be known at compile time. You also cannot set the length of the array to 5, it will be set to 1 because you are initializing one value.

Comment: okay thank you, will try this out here shortly. I set it to 5 because that's the number of objects I was planning to make but was getting the error I was getting and just hadn't yet created the other 4